# Kotlin Unresolved Reference and class function not appearing in autocmplete selection

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to follow along with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_gtvFtZjQ8

(It is a sodoku game in Kotlin)

I have my first class: SodokuBoardView, which has the following functions:

```
fun updateSelectedCellUI(row: Int, col: Int) {
    selectedRow = row
    selectedCol = col
    invalidate()
}

fun registerListener(listener: SodokuBoardView.OnTouchListener) {
    this.listener = listener
}

interface OnTouchListener {
    fun onCellTouched(row: Int, col: Int)
}
```

In the other class PlaySodokuActivity, I try and use the updateSelectedCellUI and registerListener, but I get an Unresolved Reference to those.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_sudoku)

        SodokuBoardView.registerListener(this)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PlaySodokuViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.sodokuGame.selectedCellLiveData.observe(this, Observer{ updatedSelectedCellUI(it) })
    }


    private fun updatedSelectedCellUI(cell: Pair<Int, Int>?) = cell?.let {
        SodokuBoardView.updateSelectedCellUI(cell.first, cell.second)
    }
```

Autocomplete does not even find them. (However it does find SodokuBoardView.OnTouchListener

[image: AutoComplete when typeing SodokuBoardView. into a function in PlaySodokuActivity.kt]

[image: Build Failed Errors]

What am I missing?   I have done lots of searching, but also very new to Kotlin.

Comment: You have to create an object first `var sodokuBoardView=SodokuBoardView()` or whatever your implementation is , then you can access the class methods as they are not static

Comment: But the tutorial source code doesnt have that: https://github.com/patrickfeltes/sudoku-android-kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/patrickfeltes/sudokuyoutube/view/PlaySudokuActivity.kt

Comment: yes, access it as `sudokuBoardView` in lower case as this is the viewId that you access views in [kotlin android extension](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/) this way you can find this viewId in `activity_play_sudoku.xml`

Comment: nope, then i just get a different unresolved reference:  "Unresolved reference: sodokuBoardView"

Comment: are this line exist in app `build.gradle` , `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` also do a check on the provided link

Comment: yes. and yes.  There was a typo in my xml file.  I was just following the tutorial, didn't know it was looking at the xml.  Thanks!